# How to mock Entity Framework and get the new Inserted value in the mocked context

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mocking, integration-testing, moq

I am mocking Entity Framework in a n-layer architecture. I am trying to mock an insert. The insert works, but when I try to get the values of the inserted entity, I cannot get the correct ones.

**EDIT**

This is the test case **with** the variable `pat`. In this case the test fails because the assert about the attempt date fails.

```
var mockContext = new Mock<PublicAreaContext>();

//Here I mock the entity I cannot get the correct values
PaymentAttemptTrace pat = new PaymentAttemptTrace();
var mockSetPaymentAttemptTrace = new Mock<DbSet<PaymentAttemptTrace>>();
mockContext.Setup(m => m.Set<PaymentAttemptTrace>()).Returns(mockSetPaymentAttemptTrace.Object);

//Here I create a fake request 
TracePaymentAttemptRequest request = new TracePaymentAttemptRequest();
... 

//I call the facade. The facade create a PaymentAttemptTrace and insert it in the mocked db
ToolsFacade facade = new ToolsFacade(mockContext.Object);
TracePaymentAttemptResponse response = facade.TraceAutoPayPaymentAttempt(request);

//All asserts are ok, except the last one. The date remain "empty", even if is valorized correctly during the execution of the code (I have checked in debug)
Assert.IsTrue(response.Result == it.MC.WebApi.Models.ResponseDTO.ResponseResult.Success);

mockSetPaymentAttemptTrace.Verify(m => m.Add(It.IsAny<PaymentAttemptTrace>()), Times.Once());
mockContext.Verify(m => m.SaveChanges(), Times.Once());

Assert.IsTrue(pat.AttemptDate == new DateTime(2016, 07, 27, 11, 46, 24));
```

This is the test case **without** the variable `pat`. In this case the test fails (of course) because I have not mocked the entity!!!

```
var mockContext = new Mock<PublicAreaContext>();

//Here I create a fake request 
TracePaymentAttemptRequest request = new TracePaymentAttemptRequest();
... 

//I call the facade. The facade create a PaymentAttemptTrace and insert it in the mocked db
ToolsFacade facade = new ToolsFacade(mockContext.Object);
TracePaymentAttemptResponse response = facade.TraceAutoPayPaymentAttempt(request);

Assert.IsTrue(response.Result == it.MC.WebApi.Models.ResponseDTO.ResponseResult.Success);

mockSetPaymentAttemptTrace.Verify(m => m.Add(It.IsAny<PaymentAttemptTrace>()), Times.Once());
mockContext.Verify(m => m.SaveChanges(), Times.Once());
```

Here the code I want to test:

```
public TracePaymentAttemptResponse TraceAutoPayPaymentAttempt(TracePaymentAttemptRequest request)
{
    ...
    DateTime attemptDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(request.DataTentativoPagamento))
    {
        try
        {
            attemptDate = DateTime.ParseExact(request.DataTentativoPagamento, "yyyyMMddTHHmmss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
        catch (Exception) { /* Do nothing. attemptDate = DateTime.Now.Date; */ }
    }

    PaymentAttemptTrace trace = this.CreatePaymentAttemptTraceEntity(/* All data I need to create my entity */);

    Repository<PaymentAttemptTrace> repository = new Repository<PaymentAttemptTrace>(base.Context);
    repository.Insert(trace); // <- If not mock the entity pat, here go in exception!!

    repository.SaveChanges();

    ...
}
```

So I have to mock the `pat` variable even if I do not use it in the test! The purpose of my test is verify if the parse of the attemptDate is correct.

What can be the problem? What I miss?

Thank you

**EDIT AGAIN**
I let you see another test. This test works! In this test I have to do an update of an entity:

```
var mockContext = new Mock<PublicAreaContext>() { CallBase = true };

List<BillingCenter> billingCenters = new List<BillingCenter>()
{
    new BillingCenter() { Id = "12345600", CustomerId = "123456", PaymentMethod = PaymentMethod.Easypay }
};

var data = billingCenters.AsQueryable();

var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<T>>();
mockSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(data.Provider);
mockSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(data.Expression);
mockSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(data.ElementType);
mockSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(data.GetEnumerator());

mockContext.Setup(m => m.Set<BillingCenter>()).Returns(mockSet.Object);

mockContext.Setup(x => x.SaveChanges()).Returns(1);

//Here I create a request
UpdateEasyPayFromResultPaymentRequest request = new UpdateEasyPayFromResultPaymentRequest();
...

PublicAreaFacade facade = new PublicAreaFacade(mockContext.Object);
UpdateEasyPayFromResultPaymentResponse response = facade.UpdateEasyPayFromResultPayment(request);

Assert.IsTrue(billingCenters[0].PaymentMethod == PaymentMethod.Autopay);
```

As you can see, I create the `billingCenter` with `paymentMethod = Easypay`.. At the end of the test I do an asserto to check if the payment method of billing center has changed in `Autopay`. But I do not change the value inside the test! I change it inside the `facade.UpdateEasyPayFromResultPayment` method

Comment: What is the expected behavior with regards to the setting of the date. Not seeing `pat` being used/called anywhere in your example except for your assertion, so I suspect that unless the date is set internally to the class then it should remain default

Comment: I see the update. You still have not shown where `pat` is setup to be used in your test. In your example, `pat` is just instantiated and then asserted at the end. it is not being passed to anything. also in updated code the date is not being assigned to anything so not even seeing where you set the date. Your example is till incomplete

Comment: please provide a [mcve] so that your issue can be recreated by those trying to assist you.

Comment: That one is the complete example... so the problem is that I am not using `pat` anywhere... But so I do not understand... how do I have to test the insert of a entity that is created inside the Facade ? 
However If I comment `pat` the test throw an exception, because I have not mocked the entity `PaymentAttemptTrace`

Comment: If that is the case then you have not showed the complete example. If you remove pat then you should not even be able to compile because you use it in the assertion below.

Comment: `how do I have to test the insert of a entity that is created inside the Facade ?` - there is your problem. It is a case of design. you have `CreatePaymentAttemptTraceEntity` in your MUT what does that method do?

Comment: Here is the simple observation. Nothing in the example you showed sets the `AttemptDate` on `pat` so that assertion will always fail.

Comment: I have updated again my question... I've tried to explained why it is necessary I create the `pat` variable even if I do not use it... 
If you want (I don't know how and where), I can let you see how I do the same kind of assert (check the value of property of an entity) when I do an update. As you will see, I do not modify the mocked entity in the test method, but despite of this, the assert does not fail!

Comment: I have edited again... I wrote a test where you can see that is not necessary to change the value inside the test method

Comment: You are missing the point i mentioned about `PaymentAttemptTrace pat = new PaymentAttemptTrace();` not `var mockSetPaymentAttemptTrace = new Mock<DbSet<PaymentAttemptTrace>>();` in your snippet about removing `pat` you also removed the repository, which is why that test failed

Comment: Your last edit is a complete example. the original one is not. you properly configure the dbset in the second one. and not in the first. `pat` variable is never used apart from your assertion.

Comment: Ok but I do not understand how I have to rewrite the  test correctly :( I do not understand where is the difference from my first example and the second one where the update works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another solution to what you already discovered

```
//ARRANGE
bool patAdded = false;
PaymentAttemptTrace pat = null; //will assign a value to this when adding new entity

var mockSetPaymentAttemptTrace = new Mock<DbSet<PaymentAttemptTrace>>();
//setup a call back on Add to get the entity that was added to dbset
mockSetPaymentAttemptTrace
    .Setup(m => m.Add(It.IsAny<PaymentAttemptTrace>()))
    .Callback((PaymentAttemptTrace arg) => {
        pat = arg;
        padAdded = (pat != null);
    });

var mockContext = new Mock<PublicAreaContext>();
mockContext.Setup(m => m.Set<PaymentAttemptTrace>()).Returns(mockSetPaymentAttemptTrace.Object);
mockContext.Setup(x => x.SaveChanges()).Returns(1);//for when you save the added entity

//Here I create a fake request 
TracePaymentAttemptRequest request = new TracePaymentAttemptRequest();

... 

//I call the facade. The facade create a PaymentAttemptTrace and insert it in the mocked db
ToolsFacade facade = new ToolsFacade(mockContext.Object);

//ACT
TracePaymentAttemptResponse response = facade.TraceAutoPayPaymentAttempt(request);

//ASSERT
Assert.IsTrue(response.Result == it.MC.WebApi.Models.ResponseDTO.ResponseResult.Success);

mockSetPaymentAttemptTrace.Verify(m => m.Add(It.IsAny<PaymentAttemptTrace>()), Times.Once());
mockContext.Verify(m => m.SaveChanges(), Times.Once());

Assert.IsTrue(patAdded);
Assert.IsTrue(pat.AttemptDate == new DateTime(2016, 07, 27, 11, 46, 24));
```

Comment: no I am sorry.... I like your solution much more than mine but `pat` remains null

Comment: @Ciccio If the answer you posted works then `pat` in my answer is suppose to be set when your code tries to add new entity to db set.

Comment: I don't know... perhaps I have to do a return inside the `Callback` function? However when I debug `args` is correctly valorized

Comment: You shouldn't have to. If `args` is correctly populated while debugging something else may be resetting `pat` to `null`

Comment: I have done step by step, I do not set to `null` the object... It seems everything is ok untill I come back to the test method

Comment: and the callback is being called? This is very strange. I am at a loss now. I have many tests just like this one and everything works as expected.

Comment: yes... it is called, and args is correctly valorized... uff... I'll write everything.. perhaps I miss something.. all this test I am doing my code is really dirty now..

Answer (score 1):

I have solved in this way

```
var mockContext = new Mock<PublicAreaContext>();

//Here I mock the entity I cannot get the correct values
List<PaymentAttemptTrace> pat = new List<PaymentAttemptTrace>();
var mockSetPaymentAttemptTrace = new Mock<DbSet<PaymentAttemptTrace>>();
mockSetPaymentAttemptTrace.Setup(m => m.Add(It.IsAny<PaymentAttemptTrace>())).Callback<PaymentAttemptTrace>(list.Add);
mockContext.Setup(m => m.Set<PaymentAttemptTrace>()).Returns(mockSetPaymentAttemptTrace.Object);

mockContext.Setup(x => x.SaveChanges()).Returns(1);

//Here I create a fake request 
TracePaymentAttemptRequest request = new TracePaymentAttemptRequest();
... 

//I call the facade. The facade create a PaymentAttemptTrace and insert it in the mocked db
ToolsFacade facade = new ToolsFacade(mockContext.Object);
TracePaymentAttemptResponse response = facade.TraceAutoPayPaymentAttempt(request);

//All asserts are ok, except the last one. The date remain "empty", even if is valorized correctly during the execution of the code (I have checked in debug)
Assert.IsTrue(response.Result == it.MC.WebApi.Models.ResponseDTO.ResponseResult.Success);

mockSetPaymentAttemptTrace.Verify(m => m.Add(It.IsAny<PaymentAttemptTrace>()), Times.Once());
mockContext.Verify(m => m.SaveChanges(), Times.Once());

Assert.IsTrue(pat[0].AttemptDate == new DateTime(2016, 07, 27, 11, 46, 24));
```

Here the differences compare to my question:

```
List<PaymentAttemptTrace> pat = new List<PaymentAttemptTrace>();
var mockSetPaymentAttemptTrace = new Mock<DbSet<PaymentAttemptTrace>>();
mockSetPaymentAttemptTrace.Setup(m => m.Add(It.IsAny<PaymentAttemptTrace>())).Callback<PaymentAttemptTrace>(list.Add);
```

And

```
mockContext.Setup(x => x.SaveChanges()).Returns(1);
```

I do not like this solution, onestly... but it works!!! I wait for something better! Thank you